# javascript bind to existing function

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```
myFunction = function() {
    console.log('myFunction');
}

setInterval(function () {
    myfunction();
}, 1000);
```

I would like to bind another function secondFunction() to run whenever myFunction is called.

The simple answer would be:

```
myFunction = function() {
    console.log('myFunction');
    secondFunction();
}
```

OR

```
setInterval(function () {
    myfunction();
    secondFunction();
}, 1000);
```

Although assume I don't have the ability to edit the original code I only have the ability to add new code.

How would I: Bind secondFunction() to myFunction()

Comment: Bind typically refers to executing a function in the context of a particular object. Why don't you just call the second function in the body of the first one?